# math output on C++ (checked against other language)

Tags: c++, julia

I am writing this in C++:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"print "<< int(((float(979430543) - float(800445804))/2.0)+.5);
}

for output: 89492352
```

and checking against julia language:

```
print(Int64(((Float64(979430543) - Float64(800445804))/2.0)+.5))
89492370
```

The difference between the results is 18 - what am i missing?

Comment: `int(((float(979430543) - float(800445804))/2.0)+.5)` -- Why not print out the individual components, so that you see where the differences are?  That's what any programmer should do, instead of trying to digest everything into a single line.  Somewhere, the difference in the Julia code and C++ code will show up if you broke that line up into several variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`float` in C++ is most likely to be 32 bits, while `Float64` is, well, surely 64 bits wide. Change your `float` casts to `double` casts in the C++ version and it will [surely produce the expected output](https://godbolt.org/z/e5jvb89qs).

Answer (score 6):

You are not using equivalent data types.

`Int64` should translate to `std::int64_t` and `Float64` typically to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.7.2> n = 979430543
979430543

1.7.2> n - Int(Float32(n))
15

1.7.2> n - Int(Float64(n))
0
```

The Julia result is correct. As others have said, you are using `Float32` in your C++ code.